# Can't find the .m file for UITableViewController

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5, storyboard

I realize this is likely an inane question, but here goes:

I'd like to set the background of a uitableview by code (created using storyboard), however... the only .h file I can find is in the uitableviewcontroller.h in the frameworks folder. There's no .m file anywhere that I can see, and I need to place code in the "viewdidload" for that particular table.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Never change anything inside frameworks folder. Just expand your all groups take a screen shot and post it here. How did you created the table view? from template or by your self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own class that extends `UITableViewController`. There you can override `viewDidLoad` and put your code there. Then, in your storyboard, set the custom class for your table view controller to the class you created. You do that in the 3rd tab inside the right-side pane.

Even if the source code for `UITableViewController` were available (and it is not, since Cocoa is a closed-source framework), your changes there would apply everywhere that class is used, which is never a great idea :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I swear I tried this--(mimic'ing what I learned from plain viewcontrollers.) Thanks for the quick and helpful reply- all is well =)